# How to make this Sql Consult

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:

```
T1
C1 C2 (Columns)
A  1
B  2

T2
C1 C2 (Columns)
A  Null
C Null
```

what I expect as result is:

```
C1 C2 (Columns)
A  1
B  2
C  NULL
```

please help, I try to find the most clean solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this:

```
Select case when T1.C1 is Null then T2.C1 else T1.C1 end As C1, 
      T1.C2 
from T1 FULL OUTER JOIN  T2 on T1.C1 = T2.C1
```

Comment: So is this your less clean solution and you're trying to find a better approach?

Comment: I find this solution later, I think is what I was looking for. Thanks.